# Cross compiled new version of node.js for Raspberry Pi results in 5X larger executable

Tags: node.js, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi

I cross compiled a more recent version of node.js (v0.8.14) for the Raspberry Pi.
Comparing the new version to the node v0.6.19 installed via apt-get, I was surprised that the size of the executable jumped from 1.2Mb to 6.2Mb.

Is the 5x increase in size due to

- Newer version of node: v0.6.19 --> v0.6.19
- GNU/Linux version:  2.6.26 --> 3.5.0
- something else?

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ /usr/bin/node -v; ll -h /usr/bin/node; file /usr/bin/node
v0.6.19
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.2M Jun 30 18:55 /usr/bin/node
/usr/bin/node: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), 
for GNU/Linux 2.6.26,uildID[sha1]=0xb29e21fbf3e8a7db733fbcd0539e593264d88c94, stripped

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ./node -v; ll -h ./node; file ./node
v0.8.14
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 6.2M Oct 28 20:43 ./node
./node: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), 
for GNU/Linux 3.5.0, stripped
```

Comment: I can't check currently, but you can answer your first question by compiling 0.6.19 yourself and comparing. Maybe whoever made the package had different optimizations on.

Comment: Node, between 0.6 and 0.8 does things like include it's own OpenSSL now, depending on config switches.  Could be something like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a closer look at both binaries with `readelf`, the majority of the size increase is because the larger binary is using a number of statically linked code -- the smaller binary is linked against more shared libraries.

FYI: The shared libraries linked in the smaller node were [libssl.so.1.0.0], [libz.so.1], [libv8.so.3.8.9.20], [ld-linux-armhf.so.3], [libcares.so.2], [libcrypto.so.1.0.0], [libev.so.4],  & [libutil.so.1].